# Как проверить поддержку браузером spread operator'а?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Возможно ли в JavaScript проверить, поддерживает ли браузер spread operator? Будет ли в этом браузере работать следующая конструкция?

```
var array = [...arg];
```

Comment: очевидно обернуть в try catch

Comment: @Grundy, можно подробнее в ответе к вопросу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

в данном случае поможет [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) и [`try..catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

при попытке выполнить код с использованием spread оператора в браузере, который его не поддерживает будет кинуто исключение об ошибке синтаксиса, поэтому проверяющая функция может выглядеть так:

```js
function checkSpread() {
  try {
    return eval('[...[]]==""');
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(checkSpread());
```

Текущий сниппет, например в IE11 вернет false, а в Chrome - true

Вместо [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) так же можно использовать конструктор [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

```js
function checkSpread() {
  try {
    var func = new Function('return [...[]]');
    return func() == '';
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(checkSpread());
```

Comment: Второй вариант более действенный, так как с помощью него можно любое подобной свойство проверить

Comment: @Yuri, они равнозначны